# Custom error class in airflow generates weird string error

Tags: exception, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to create a custom error class to be used in airflow. If I create a class that inherits from `AirflowException`

```
class AirflowCustomException(AirflowException):
     """ My exception """
```

the tasks is not retried when it fails.
However, if my custom class inherits from `Exception`, or from `ValueError` as in:

```
class MyCustomException(Exception):
    """my custom exception""

def _raise_custom_exception() -> None:
    raise MyCustomException("Value not found")
    

raise_custom_exception = PythonOperator(
    task_id='raise_custom_exception',
    python_callable=_raise_custom_exception,
    dag=dag
)
```

the task is retried correctly, but the error contains some weird `unusual_prefix_` string:

```
raise MyCustomException("Value not found")
unusual_prefix_1dc4b55f1966fa9d58278be01ae2ddbea7022600_trial_custom_exception.MyCustomException: Value not found
```

What is the right way of creating a custom exception that allows the task to be retried when it fails?

Comment: what version of Airflow is this? Do you recognize any components of the prefix from elsewhere in your code base?

Comment: it's airflow 2.4 and I don't see any component of the prefix in my code